# Serialized data list to foreach

Tags: php, serialization, multidimensional-array, foreach

How can I list the serialized data retrieved from the database. My code is failing.

PHP 5.6

My data

```
a:3:{i:0;a:4:{s:2:"no";i:2;s:4:"name";s:23:"file-417-1546062916.zip";s:4:"type";s:28:"application/x-zip-compressed";s:4:"size";i:31835501;}i:1;a:4:{s:2:"no";i:1;s:4:"name";s:23:"file-417-1546063067.zip";s:4:"type";s:28:"application/x-zip-compressed";s:4:"size";i:31835501;}i:2;a:4:{s:2:"no";i:3;s:4:"name";s:23:"file-417-1546063154.zip";s:4:"type";s:28:"application/x-zip-compressed";s:4:"size";i:31835501;}}
```

My code

```
$fileStr = $getMeta('post_files', $pID);
$list = ($fileStr) ? unserialize($fileStr) : '';
foreach ($list as $k => $v) {
     echo $k.' - '.$v;
}
```

> Notice: Array to string conversion in ..........
>   0 - Array

Comment: Did you look at what the array looks like? Did you try a var_dump/print_r?

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a multidimensional array which means you need two foreach nested.

```
$str = 'a:3:{i:0;a:4:{s:2:"no";i:2;s:4:"name";s:23:"file-417-1546062916.zip";s:4:"type";s:28:"application/x-zip-compressed";s:4:"size";i:31835501;}i:1;a:4:{s:2:"no";i:1;s:4:"name";s:23:"file-417-1546063067.zip";s:4:"type";s:28:"application/x-zip-compressed";s:4:"size";i:31835501;}i:2;a:4:{s:2:"no";i:3;s:4:"name";s:23:"file-417-1546063154.zip";s:4:"type";s:28:"application/x-zip-compressed";s:4:"size";i:31835501;}}';
$list = unserialize($str);
if(!empty($list)){ // check if the array/string is empty
    foreach ($list as $k => $v) {
        echo $k . "\n";
        foreach($v as $k2 => $val){
            echo $k2.' - '.$val . "\n";
        }
        echo "\n\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
no - 2
name - file-417-1546062916.zip
type - application/x-zip-compressed
size - 31835501


1
no - 1
name - file-417-1546063067.zip
type - application/x-zip-compressed
size - 31835501


2
no - 3
name - file-417-1546063154.zip
type - application/x-zip-compressed
size - 31835501
```

https://3v4l.org/itGpB

To see what the array looks like you can use print_r/var_dump or var_export.
They will show how many levels deep your array is, if it's a unknown number of levels then you can use array_walk_recursive to walk the array.

Comment: @Murat :-) . I see that you use a ternary to see if you want to unserialize or not. Unserialize will fail silently and not create any problems. Foreach however will not fail silently. I would remove the ternary and add a if empty as this: https://3v4l.org/p2hUn that way if the string is empty no problems.